# Sequelize - are there bidirectional associations?

Tags: javascript, orm, associations, sequelize.js

In the documentation of the Sequelize ORM http://docs.sequelizejs.com/ I don't see any reference to bidirectional associations between models, as we know from Java's Hibernate or PHP's Doctrine.

So, Sequelize does not support bidirectional associations out of the box?

Comment: Do you mean M:N associations? [Here] is the explanation. Or you mean when you set `hasMany` on the Origin model but also one to access from the Destination model? (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#belongs-to-many-associations)

Comment: The bidirectional associations can be created in one-to-one, one-to-many ones as well. In case of one-to-one, if a user has a task, we can do `user.getTask()` *as well* as `task.getUser()`. It is not there.

Comment: Ok, sequelize does not do that by default, you have to indicate on the models `User.hasMany(Task)` and then `Task.belongsTo(User)`. I recommend use an alias `:as` on the `hasMany` and then after the creation of the database you ser `belongsTo` with an alias also to the other model. I know sounds very ridiculous, but is the best way to do it as far I've been working with sequelize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by out of the box.

Bidirectional associations in Sequelize are achieved by defining two single associations on each respective model. As far as i know there is no other way.

eg. We have a User Model and a Post Model. The Post model holds a foreign key from User named UserId, this is a one to many association. To achieve that bidirectionally you  should add an association on the User Model as well as the Post model as below.

```
User.associate = function(models) {
    models.User.hasMany(models.Post, {
        foreignKey:"UserId"
    })
}

Post.associate = function(models)  {
    models.Post.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey:"UserId"
    })
}
```

Similar approaches go for any kind of association type. I know it seems like not the most convenient thing.

Comment: It works when I also add the `belongsTo` to the `hasMany`. So it is possible. I am not sure about the `foreignKey` syntax; it gives me error.

Comment: What sequelize version are you using?

Comment: also check this [link](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html) on target keys..

Comment: The version is 4.39.1. It ends with SQL error. (MySQL). I would expect something like inverse, backref in one of the models.

Comment: I am on 4.38.0 but on Postgres dialect. It was propably my fault for writing that, maybe MySQL does not support the target keys. still it makes little difference since the foreign key ids of yours are set by convention meaning, most likely, you had no need for target keys in the first place. :)

Comment: Instead of `hasMany`, I'm trying to do `hasOne`, but that doesn't seem to want to work.